# Unity lost almost all shortcuts

Tags: unity, nvidia, unity-2d

I have a Dell latitude E6530 laptop with NVidia video card that was working fine with the default video driver.

After a normal package update (~1 week ago) and a restart, boot resulted in a blank screen and I could run Ubuntu only with safe mode.

In safe mode all my "cool" shortcuts were disabled. i.e.

```
ctrl+Super+ LeftKey
Ctri+Super+ RightKey
Ctrl+Alt+Numpad [1379]
Super+w
and Alt+Tab had a very flat design  (I think I was switched to Unity2D)
```

I managed to restore normal boot by installing the nvidia driver (nvidia-current) and reinstalling X11.
However the shortcuts were not restored and I am still in Unity 2D.

I cannot even see these shortcuts in the system preferences anymore so I am not sure if Ubuntu decided to ditch them completely or I can restore them in another way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed [Bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) and after a reboot all worked out

Answer (score 0):

maybe this bug affecting nvidia users
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1166765

try the temp fix - open a terminal    and execute the following:

$ gsettings reset org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ active-plugins
$ shutdown -r now

fixes it but maybe not permanently yet so keep this note handy.

Comment: this doesn't work for me. I get `No such schema 'org.compiz.core'
`

Answer (score 0):

This actually solved it for me, so I now can use the new drivers

```
gsettings reset org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ active-plugins
```